# Difference between PCA done in R and Python

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, pca

My colleague and I are comparing PCA done in R and Python. She is using `princomp()` function in R, whereas I am using PCA from `sklearn.decomposition`. What is interesting, after fitting scaled data into `pca.fit` and applying the dimensional reduction we receive totally different loadings for PC1. The difference is the sign - all components with positive (negative) sign in R are having negative (positive) sign in Python. We then fit the result into linear regression model and unsurprisingly, we receive different coefficient sign (whereas intercept is the same). We also are having the same R squared value for the model.

Python:

```
Coefficients: 
 [-0.17878575]
Intercept: 
 0.6805798284875717
```

R:

```
Coefficients: 
 [0.17878575]
Intercept: 
 0.6805798284875717
```

Python code goes as follows:

```
scaled_data = pd.DataFrame(preprocessing.scale(df_target_features),columns = df_target_features.columns) 

# mean vector to compute covariance matrix
mean_vector = np.mean(scaled_data, axis=0)

# covarariance matrix, representation of variance of all features in the original data set
cov_matrix = (scaled_data - mean_vector).T.dot((scaled_data - mean_vector)) / (scaled_data.shape[0]-1)

# performing eigen decomposition on covariance matrix to find eigen values and eigen vector to find where is the maximum variance in the data
eigen_vals, eigen_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_matrix)

# visually confirm that the list is correctly sorted by decreasing eigenvalues
eigen_pairs = [(np.abs(eigen_vals[i]), eigen_vecs[:, i]) for i in range(len(eigen_vals))]
for i in eigen_pairs:
    print (i[0])




# initialize pca object
components = 1
pca = PCA(n_components=components)


# Fit the model with X and apply the dimensionality reduction on X.The new components are just the two main dimensions of variation.
pca.fit(scaled_data)

# X features - principal components
X_reg = pca.fit_transform(scaled_data)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)

explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
pca_components = pca.components_

Y = Y.reset_index(drop=True)

# constructing data frame with principal components (result of dimension reduction)
principal_df = pd.DataFrame(data=X_reg, columns=['PC_' + str(i) for i in range(1, components + 1)])

# we can concatenate principal components with target (Y) variable
final_df = pd.concat([principal_df, Y], axis=1)

comp_df = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_, columns=scaled_data.columns, index=['PC_' + str(i) for i in range(1, components + 1)])

# explained variance

plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('Number of components')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative explained variance')
plt.show()


# Create linear regression object

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Fit 
regr.fit(X_reg, Y)

# calibration 
y_c = regr.predict(X_reg)

sc = regr.score(X_reg, Y)

# The coefficients
# coefficients = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_reg.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(regr.coef_))], axis = 1)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)


# Cross-validation; The parameter cv=10 means that we divide the data in 10 parts and hold out one part for cross validation.
y_cv = cross_val_predict(regr, X_reg, Y, cv=10)
# Calculate scores for calibration and cross-validation
score_c = r2_score(Y, y_c)
score_cv = r2_score(Y, y_cv)
# Calculate mean square error for calibration and cross validation
mse_c = mean_squared_error(Y, y_c)
mse_cv = mean_squared_error(Y, y_cv)
```

How can we decide who is having correct results and when I should investigate at first?

Comment: Both results are correct.

Comment: What causes the difference then?

Comment: If you mean difference in coefficients, then the answer is different signs of loadings. If you mean different signs of loadings then this might be due to differences in algos. But the difference in signs does not cancel the fact that (1) 1st PC will be one with most variability, PC2 will be second and so on (2) the new dimensions will be orthogonal. Differences in sign simply mean flipping axes, from geometric standpoint.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyBushmanov. That is really helpful to understand it. Especially the fact that there might be differences in algos because the difference in coefficients result straight from the different loadings signs.

Comment: Something interesting I found is that by default eigenvectors in R point in the negative direction.  [Here](https://uc-r.github.io/pca) is the resource I found it, what they did is multiplied the loadings  by -1